# How to center a RadioButtonList in a table cell

Tags: html, css, radiobuttonlist

This should be dead easy. How do you center a radiobuttonlist? It didn't used to be hard. 
The below HTML does not work. What am I missing?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                      <td  style="text-align: center">
                          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radUserType" runat="server" 
                              RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                          </asp:RadioButtonList>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
           </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for your layout. Use CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html Oh, and don't use inline-styling.

Comment: I use a stylesheet, but for this example, I wanted to make it very simple. And I don't belive "don't use tables" is a serious answer.

Comment: Of course it isn't. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Do you want it to be centered in yout `<td>` ?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

RepeatLayout="Flow"

Renders the RadioButtonList in a span rather than a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using td attributes :

```
<td align="center"> 
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radUserType" runat="server" 
       RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
       </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, that works in this example, but not on my page, which uses CSS. It seems as if some CSS attribute up the line is overriding the "align=center". So, it would seem the remedy would be to add a CSS style directly in the cell. Shouldn't that be used before other up-line CSS?

Comment: Using Chrome. If I use <p align="center">, it renders as centered in VS2010, but when I view in the browser, it's back to left justify.

Comment: Viewing the page, radiobuttonlist LEFT justified, hwere is the source HTML. This makes no sense.  

<p align="center">
                <table id="radUserType" class="norm12">
 <tr>
  <td><input id="radUserType_0" type="radio" name="radUserType" value="Student" /><label for="radUserType_0">Student</label></td><td><input id="radUserType_1" type="radio" name="radUserType" value="Teacher" /><label for="radUserType_1">Teacher</label></td><td><input id="radUserType_2" type="radio" name="radUserType" value="Parent" /><label for="radUserType_2">Parent</label></td>
 </tr>
</table>
                </p>